# Anyone sees this sentence awkward?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence

Take a look at the following sentence

> Some psychologists have characterized all infant language-learning as
> problem-solving, extending to children such scientific procedures as
> "learning by experiment," or "hypothesis-testing."

This sentence is just a small portion of the text that I'm supposed to solve problems with.

I'm not a native English speaker, but I lived long enough in America and I know an awkward sentence when I read one.

This sentence just sounds "wrong" to me.

The first part of the sentence, everything before the comma, sounds just fine. But after the comma, even though I understand what it's trying to say, it just seems so awkward.

I tried to change the sentence by switching the order, like

> Some psychologists have characterized all infant language-learning as
> problem-solving, extending such scientific procedures as "learning by
> experiment," or "hypothesis-testing." to children.

But the thing is, the sentence still seems awkward to me.

I just want to know if this sentence is grammatically correct and is using the standard structure of a sentence.

It would also be helpful if someone could actually tell me what this sentence is talking about.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

EDIT:

I don't understand the second part of the sentence. To simplify the sentence, I wrote out the sentence like

> extending to children such A as B.

I don't understand how this could be a 'correct sentence', nor do I understand what it's trying to say.

Comment: The second comma, before _or_, is unnecessary. And in any case it should be after the quotation mark, not before it. Otherwise the sentence is fine.

Comment: The clause you are asking about applies the principle of _end-weight_. In other words, longer, 'heavier' elements are placed at the end of the clause. _..., extending such scientific procedures as "learning by experiment" or "hypothesis-testing" to children_ contravenes end-weight. https://www.thoughtco.com/end-weight-grammar-1690594#:~:text=In%20grammar%2C%20end%2Dweight%20is,Grammar%20of%20English%2C%202008

Comment: @Shoe It should only be after the quotation mark in UK style. In US style, putting it inside the quotation mark is correct. (Per all common style guides anyway.)

Comment: @Jason. Thanks for pointing that out. I researched this a bit, and found out that only commas and periods go inside the quotation marks in US English. Other punctuation goes outside. The full stop inside the quotation mark at the end of the OP's sentence seems odd to me!